# Как скопировать сообщение в aiogram полностью?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Использовал copy_message, но он копирует только текст. Как копировать вообще все, что отправил пользователь? (фото, видео, форматирование текста и т.п.) Например в telebot если используешь copy_message, то он копирует все целиком.

Comment: дальнейшая какая задача с копированным сообщением? если для пересылки в другой чат, то можно использовать `await message.copy_to(chat_id=...)`, где `chat_id` - id чата, в который хотите переслать

Comment: пробовал этот вариант, отправляю фото - молчит. отправляю текст - копирует в чат. понимаю что можно реализовать через types.ContentType.PHOTO, но все же нельзя как то по другому?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете 3ю версию aiogram, то могу вот такой вариант предложить:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, Router

TOKEN = ''
router = Router()


@router.message()
async def forward_msg(message: types.Message):
    await message.copy_to(chat_id=) # Тут id чата, в который пересылать


async def main() -> None:
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    bot = Bot(TOKEN)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

пересылает любой контент, не только текст